# Why isn't Rails automatically creating join table entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple has_many through relationship set up:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profile_tags
  has_many :profiles, :through => :profile_tags
end

class ProfileTags < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profile_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :profile_tags
end
```

From my view I am accepting a set of tags (just strings), and am iterating over them in my controller and calling Tag.create( ... ) on each of them, and pushing them into an array. This all works fine.

So I get to a point where I have an Array of Tag objects (tags) which were each returned by the call to create, and variable @profile which was created by doing Profile.new

I would like to do: `@profile.tags = tags`

Doing this causes this error on the line where I try the assignment:

```
uninitialized constant Profile::ProfileTag
```

Rails is acting like I need to manually create and assign the join table association, even though here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association it states that when you do an assignment like this, new associations will be created and if some are gone they will be deleted.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails assumes that model classes are named with the singular form, i.e. the class `ProfileTags` should be called `ProfileTag`.

Depending on which Rails version you are using, probably the easiest way to fix this is to re-create the model using `script/destroy` and `script/generate` in Rails 2.x or `rails destroy` and `rails generate` in Rails 3.

Alternatively, specifying the class name manually by adding `:class_name => 'ProfileTags'` to the `has_many` declarations should work too.